# Value not displayed in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Here's my simple html for three radio buttons:

```
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input name="bulkaudit"
                                                class="form-check-input"
                                                type="radio"
                                                [(ngModel)]="decidedAsMember"
                                                [disabled]="oneByOneAudit"
                                                [value]="true"> Member
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input  class="form-check-input"
                                                    name="bulkaudit"
                                                    ng-control="bulkaudit"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="decidedAsMember"
                                                    [disabled]="oneByOneAudit"
                                                    [value]="false"> Non-Member
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input  class="form-check-input"
                                                    name="bulkaudit"
                                                    ng-control="bulkaudit"
                                                    type="radio"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="purge"
                                                    [disabled]="oneByOneAudit"
                                                    [value]="Purge"> Purge past decisions
                                        </label>
                                        <div>Your decision is: {{decidedAsMember}}</div>
                                        <div>Your decision is: {{purge}}</div>
                                    </div>
```

When I toggled over `Member` or `Non-Member` buttons, this `div` does show values properly as `Your decision is: true` or `Your decision is: false`, however, when I selected `Purge past decisions`, it doesn't display any values `Your XCP decision is:`

I tried to `console.log` this field, it's `undefined`.

Anyone could shed any light on this please?

Comment: [value]="’Purge’" maybe? (Additional single quotes)

Comment: You nailed it!!! Thanks! This did the magic!

Comment: @MikeOne Feel free to put this as an answer and I'll accept it. I think it might help others in the future as well. Also, could you help me reason why this string needs to be enclosed with single quotes while boolean values don't? Thanks!